# How to change android indeterminate ProgressBar color?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I would like to know how I can change indeterminate `ProgressBar` color from basis white/grey color to black ? When I change the `indeterminateDrawable`, I get a static image instead of a moving animated progressBar. Is there any way to do it simply in XML?

Answer (score 85):

```
progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(
            getResources().getColor(Your_Color),
            android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

and replace Your_Color with the desired color like: R.color.your_color_code

Comment: This is the most quick and easy way.

Comment: Could define in xml: `android:indeterminateTint="@colors/your_color"` `android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"`

Comment: @zhaoyuanjie android:indeterminateTint only works on API level 21+

Comment: I'm glad I scrolled down - this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: is all that porter duff business really necessary? :(

Comment: unfortunately this does not work for some devices, for example on the HUAWEI Mate9 this does not work :( I would advise to use a layer drawable  :(

Answer (score 64):

To get a ProgressBar in the default theme that is to be used on white/light back ground, use one of the inverse styles:

```
<ProgressBar style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"/>
<ProgressBar style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large.Inverse"/>
<ProgressBar style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small.Inverse"/>
```

This will usually give you a black on transparent ProgressBar, but some OS installs use custom assets.  If you're looking for a specific color, you'll have to roll your own drawables by following the instructions provided by CommonsWare.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a device-agnostic solution. On my LG Optimus 2X Speed, an indeterminate ProgressBar is still always black, while on a HTC Desire HD with CyanogenMod for 2.3.3, it is always red.

Comment: @Paul - Yes, you are correct.  Many device manufactures customize the themes, and the default theme can change between Android versions.  I'll correct the text above

Answer (score 42):

I see other answers are quite old, in order to change the indeterminate ProgressBar color you have just to set [`android:indeterminateTint`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#attr_android:indeterminateTint) and [`android:indeterminateTintMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#attr_android:indeterminateTintMode) attributes in your [`ProgressBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) item directly in XML:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"
    android:indeterminate="true" />
```

[`android:indeterminateTint`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#attr_android:indeterminateTint) - Tint to apply to the indeterminate progress indicator.

> Must be a color value, in the form of `"#rgb"`, `"#argb"`, `"#rrggbb"`, `"#aarrggbb"`, or a reference to a resource `@color/colorPrimary`.

[`android:indeterminateTintMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#attr_android:indeterminateTintMode) - Blending mode used to apply the progress indicator tint.

> Must be one of the following constant values:
>   `add`, `multiply`, `screen`, `src_atop`, `src_in` or `src_over`

Getter and Setter methods for these attributes are:

- [`getIndeterminateTintList()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#getIndeterminateTintList())
- [`getIndeterminateTintMode()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#getIndeterminateTintMode())
- [`setIndeterminateTintList(ColorStateList tint)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setIndeterminateTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList))
- [`setIndeterminateTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode tintMode)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setIndeterminateTintMode(android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode))

All of them were added in [API level 21](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels)

Comment: So frustrating!  In android studio you have to use the View All Attributes option to access indeterminateTintMode and then change it to src_in...I was NOT going to figure this out on my own.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I make sample project and post in in my blog. Please, look at. http://www.hrupin.com/2011/09/21/how-to-make-custom-indeterminate-progressbar-in-android-or-how-to-change-progressbar-style-or-color

Hope, it help you

Answer (score 6):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/bg" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress" android:drawable="@drawable/secondary" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/progress" />
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 3):

For API less than 23 use

```
progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(
       getResources().getColor(Your_Color),
        android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

else use

```
progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(
        ContextCompat.getColor(context, Your_Color),
        android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Answer (score 1):

Override `android:colorControlActivated` in your AppTheme which should be in your styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="...">
    ...
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/beautiful_color</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Works on API 21+

Comment: Easiest way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the Material Component Library you can use the **`CircularProgressIndicator`** with these attributes:

- `indicatorColor`
- `trackColor`

Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
       android:indeterminate="true"
       app:trackColor="@color/red600Light"
       app:indicatorColor="@color/red600Dark"
       app:indicatorSize="50dp"
       .../>
```

[image]

You can also use a Multi-color indeterminate indicator.

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
            android:indeterminate="true"
            app:trackColor="@color/red600Light"
            app:indicatorColor="@array/progress_colors"
            app:indeterminateAnimationType="contiguous"/>
```

with `array/progress_colors`:

```
  <integer-array name="progress_colors">
    <item>@color/...</item>
    <item>@color/...</item>
    <item>@color/...</item>
  </integer-array>
```

Answer (score -5):

actually all u need to do (for both cirle and bar) is create an xml file in drawable as shown below...... 
progress_spinner_001 points to whatever image u want to animate and duration ... how long u want to display each frame for.......
and set ur android:indeterminateDrawable= filename_in_drawable....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/progress_spinner_001" android:duration="300" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/progress_spinner_002" android:duration="300" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/progress_spinner_003" android:duration="300" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/progress_spinner_004" android:duration="300" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/progress_spinner_005" android:duration="300" />
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/progress_spinner_006" android:duration="300" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/progress_spinner_007" android:duration="300" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/progress_spinner_008" android:duration="300" />
</animation-list>
```

ps u may need to resize the progressbar to show as desired

Comment: -1: this answer says "as shown below" but it shows nothing. I find it very hard to understand.