# color of progress bar

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change progress bar's progress color in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android)

Hi,
I want to change the color of progress bar from yellow to bleu 
how to do this?

Comment: Already asked before, please use Google. Related question: -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android/2021119#2021119

Comment: I see that but I didn't understand how to use this. I just need to chenge the color

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: [How to change android indeterminate ProgressBar color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638161/how-to-change-android-indeterminate-progressbar-color)

You have to use and modify the default Drawables.