# ProgressBar thickness

Tags: android

Look at the images below :

- [image]
- [image]
- [image]

On each image `ProgressBar` has different style from another ProgressBar's.

I want to know, how i can specify progress bar **style/thin** in my application.

I look at `android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall` but it just change a size of progress bar, not a thickness of a spinning circle.

> Note : Don't post answers which suppose create a custom drawables. ***Libraries allow.***

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25547421/2649012

Answer (score 5):

You may try this git library it will help you and give more customization ...

https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar

```
mProgressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(new SmoothProgressDrawable.Builder(context)
    .strokeWidth(8f)            //You should use Resources#getDimension
    .build());
```

You can give any stroke width here.

Answer (score 5):

Can't say whether you can deal with these default progress bars, but you can try with an alternative design your own progress image and perform animation over it like here,

[image]

Now add this in res/drawable/customprogress.xml

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="360" >
    <shape
        android:shape="oval"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <size
            android:height="48dip"
            android:width="48dip" />
        <gradient
            android:centerColor="#ff000000"
            android:centerY="0.50"
            android:endColor="#ff00ff00"
            android:startColor="#ff000000"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

and add this progressbar attribute

```
android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/customprogress"
```