# android custom color progressbar style

Tags: android, coding-style, colors, progress-bar

I am a lot confused with styles. Need help. How can I create a progressBar style in xmls, generic, but backgroung red and progressbar green?
thanks.

Comment: See if this post helps you out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638161/how-to-change-android-indeterminate-progressbar-color

Answer (score 1):

Use a layer list which provides the background and the item to use to "fill in" the progress.

Something like this - my_progress_bar.xml (put this in your Drawable folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
          android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar" > </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/progressfill"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then, instantiate a `SeekBar` in your `View`:

```
seekBar = new SeekBar(context);
seekBar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_progress_bar));
```

Note that `SeekBar` is a subclass of `ProgressBar`, but you should be able to do something similar for a `progressbar`.

Comment: is there any way I can write over the progressBar and not with another control around it?, i.e. I want to put % completed inside the progress bar

Comment: I dont understand, in your example, where does I write red and green?