# How can I remove default attributes from Android views when loaded from XML?

Tags: android, user-interface, user-experience, seekbar

I am working on an app that uses some basic view types, but I find the default attributes extremely ugly in Android (for example, a bright yellow `SeekBar`). I can get the basic seekbar if I create it from code, using only the `context` parameter, but I would like to know if there is a way to do this inside an XML Layout file. Is there an attribute I can set that will remove all default attributes - such as `android:style="@null"`?

Comment: The default attributes depend on the flavour of Android. In Android 2.2 the default is yellow, in 4.x they're blue. But if you look at the HTC or Samsung flavours they customize those colours - on HTC it is/was lime green.

Why not just force the style with your own Theme and not allow the phones to use their custom colours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two *right* answers. The first is to set the theme, such as how it is done for [How to change android indeterminate ProgressBar color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638161/how-to-change-android-indeterminate-progressbar-color). The second option is to set the progress and thumb attributes as discussed in [Seek bar, change path color from yellow to white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480456/seek-bar-change-path-color-from-yellow-to-white)

Answer (score 0):

You can always create your own style for widgets, providing your own colors and drawables, if you don't like default ones.