# Changing background color of Indeterminate Horizontal ProgressBar

Tags: android

I've seen some topics about handling colors of ProgressBars but none could answer my doubt.

I am using a horizontal `ProgressBar` Indeterminate type.
I want it to have a transparent background while having a colored progressBar but cannot find a way to do it.

For a normal ProgressBar (not Indeterminate) I can get a LayerDrawable by calling `progressBar.getProgressDrawable()`. Then using `findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.background)`, I am able to tint just the background.

But using `progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable()` it returns me a `GradientDrawable`, so I can't follow the same procedure.

Is it possible to get the colors from a `GradientDrawable` for all APIs levels? Cause if it is, I could get the color of the background and change it.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Use color filter like this:

```
progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Answer (score 1):

progressBar.setProgressDrawable(R.drawable.progress_bar);

drawable/progress_bar.xml

```
<layer-list   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="2dip" />
        <gradient android:startColor="#43ffffff" android:centerColor="#43ffffff" android:centerY="0.75" android:endColor="#43ffffff" android:angle="270" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="2dip" />
            <gradient android:startColor="#fff" android:endColor="#fff" android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item> </layer-list>
```

you can change color in this progress_bar.xml drawable

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Copy `drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal.xml` from your SDK's resources into your project.

Step #2: Copy `drawable-hdpi/progressbar_indeterminate*` from your SDK's resources into your project.

Step #3: Copy `drawable-mdpi/progressbar_indeterminate*` from your SDK's resources into your project.

Step #4: Modify the PNG files to look the way you want.

Step #5: Modify the `progress_indeterminate_horizontal.xml` to point to your PNG files (versus the standard ones).

Step #6: Use `@drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal` for the `indeterminateDrawable` value.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638161/how-to-change-android-indeterminate-progressbar-color)

Else

```
progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable()
    .setColorFilter(progressBar.getContext().getResources().getColor(<colorId>),
        PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: This will change all Indeterminate progress bars in my project, right? If so, is there any workaround to apply it for a single progressbar in my project?

Comment: @AndroidDev, (1st.) for all and (2nd.)nope, for the particular one